# I can't render PreactX component directly into document.body

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, preact

Please see this minimum example:

[image: Edit cool-meadow-hiv9z]

Or Code:

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### JS

```js
/** @jsx h */
import { h, render } from "preact";

function App() {
  return <div className="App">Cool</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

The rendered result is this:

### Result

```html
<body>
  <div id="root" class="App">Cool</div>
</body>
```

I want to leave my `#root` dom element empty, but PreactX take over control to that dom node, why is that happening?

I would like to directly render my PreactX component into document.body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preact is basically diffing and merging the *original contents* of `document.body` (`<div id="root"></div>`) with the new contents `<div className="App">Cool</div>`, giving you this result:

`<div id="root" class="App">Cool</div>`

If you go into `public/index.html` and remove line 13: `<div id="root"></div>`, you'll see the generated html is now: `<div class="App">Cool</div>`.

TLDR; you're mounting preact to `document.body`, which already has contents, and preact is comparing and merging those contents with your 'App.js' component. Empty the body tag in index.html and you're good.